# c# wpf - DataGrid delete selected rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I am using c #, wpf, DataGrid, SqlDataAdapter, DataTable, MS Sql server
On the main form there is a DataGrid and a button.
Clicking on the button should be removed from the DataGrid selected lines. And then from the database. But this is not happening! Only from the DataGrid!
Here is my code:

```
private void Button_DeleteSelectedRows_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dataGrid.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
            {
                int selectedIndex = dataGrid.SelectedIndex;
                var row = dataTable.Rows[selectedIndex];
                row.Delete();

                dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
            }
            else if (dataGrid.SelectedItems.Count > 1)
            {
                int count = dataGrid.SelectedItems.Count;

                for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    DataRowView rowView = dataGrid.SelectedItems[i] as DataRowView;

                    dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                               .Where(r => r["Name"].ToString() == rowView.Row["Name"].ToString())
                               .ToList()
                               .ForEach(r => r.Delete());
                    dataTable.AcceptChanges();
                }
                dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

}

P.S.: I do not use MVVM

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Is any exception caught?

Comment: Where does the data table come from? If it is generated then it is clear that this will not work however if it is a table from database direct this is another case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider refactoring the for-loop into a while loop., e.g while(datagrid.SelectedItem.Count >=1).   Generally you will encounter issues when accessing an collection based on index, in case if you delete an item within a loop.

Debug Tip: Try to check count of selected Items within the for-loop loop and check if the object exists @ particular index.

Answer (score 1):

**This code works to delete selected rows. Be sure**

```
while (Mydatagrid.SelectedItems.Count >= 1)
{
 DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)Mydatagrid.SelectedItem;
 drv.Row.Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is right I guess, to remove rows from `DataTable` use following syntax:

```
datatable.Rows.Remove((myGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView).Row);
```

Or in second code block:

```
DataRowView rowView = dataGrid.SelectedItems[i] as DataRowView;
        datatable.Rows.Remove(rowView.Row);
```

then at last put

```
datatable.AcceptChanges();
```

changes should reflected properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for not having replied and kept you waiting!
Your advice helped me a lot.
I have decided this is the case:

```
else if (dataGrid.SelectedItems.Count > 1)
        {
            while (dataGrid.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
             int selectedIndex = dataGrid.SelectedIndex;
            var row = dataTable.Rows[selectedIndex];
            row.Delete();

            dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
            }
        }
```

[SOLVED]

currently I am thinking seriously alter the application to MVVM :D:D